# Match a single senerio with ANTLR and skip everything else as noise

Tags: java, parsing, coldfusion, antlr

I defined a simple grammar using an ANTLR V4 Eclipse Plugin. I want to parse a file that contains Coldfusion cfscript code, and find every instance of a property definition. For example:

```
property name="productTypeID" ormtype="string" length="32" fieldtype="id" generator="uuid" unsavedvalue="" default="";
```

That is, a property keyword followed by any number of attributes, line terminated with a semicolon.

.g4 file

```
grammar CFProperty;
property  : 'property ' (ATR'='STRING)+EOL; // match keyword property followed by an attribute definition

ATR : [a-zA-Z]+;                            // match lower and upper-case identifiers name

STRING: '"' .*? '"';                        // match any string

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;                    // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

EOL : ';';                                  // end of the property line
```

I put together a simple java project that uses the generated parser, tree-walker etc to printout the occurrences of those matches.

The input I'm testing this with is:

```
"property id=\"actionID\" name=\"actionName\" attr=\"actionAttr\"    hbMethod=\"HBMethod\"; public function some funtion  {//some text} property name=\"actionID\" name=\"actionName\" attr=\"actionAttr\" hbMethod=\"HBMethod\"; \n more noise "
```

My issue is that this is only matching:

```
property id="actionID" name="actionName" attr="actionAttr"    hbMethod="HBMethod";
```

And because it doesn't understand everthing else to be noise, it doesn't match the second instance of the property definition.

How can I match on multiple instances of the property definition and match on everything else in-between as noise to be skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lexer mode to do what you want. One mode for property and stuffs and one mode for noise. The idea behind mode is to go from a mode (a state) to another following token we found during lexing operation.

To do this, you have to cut your grammar in two files, the parser in one file and the lexer in the other.

Here is the lexer part (named `TestLexer.g4` in my case)

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

// Normal mode

PROPERTY : 'property';
EQUALS : '=';
ATR : [a-zA-Z]+;                           // match lower and upper-case identifiers name
STRING: '"' .*? '"';                       // match any string
WS : [ \t\r\n]+        -> skip;            // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
EOL : ';'              -> pushMode(NOISE); // when ';' is found, go to noise mode where everything is skip

mode NOISE;

NOISE_PROPERTY : 'property' -> type(PROPERTY), popMode;   // when 'property' is found, we say it's a PROPERTY token and we go back to  normal mode
ALL :  .+?                  -> skip;                      // skip all other stuffs
```

Here is the parser part (named `Test.g4` in my case)

```
grammar Test;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

root : property+;
property  : PROPERTY (ATR EQUALS STRING)+ EOL; // match keyword   property followed by an attribute definition
```

This should do the work :)